# pthread-based event waking up only waiting threads

Tags: events, pthreads

In my C++ program I have a class CEvent with trigger and wait member functions based on pthreads (running on Linux). Implementation is quite obvious (i.e. many examples online) if there is one waiting process. However now I need to satisfy the requirement that multiple threads are waiting on the event and should ALL wake up reliably when trigger() is called. As a second condition, only threads that were waiting when trigger() was called should wake up.

My current code:

```
void CEvent::trigger() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    wakeUp = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&condition)
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    wakeUp = false;
}

void CEvent::wait() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (!wakeUp)
        pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &mutex)

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

This seems to almost work, insofar as that all threads waiting wake up before I set wakeUp back to false. However between the broadcast and the reset of wakeUp, other (or the same) threads calling wait() will also wake up right away which is not acceptable. Putting wakeUp = false before the mutext unlocking prevents the threads from waking up.

My questions:
  * When does pthread_cond_broadcast return? I.e. is there a guarantee it will only return after all threads have woken up or could it return before?
  * Are there any recommended solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please disregard my previous bogus answer. There is a race between the time that the trigger thread unlocks the mutex (and thus frees the waiting threads), and then sets the wakeUp value. This means that another (not waiting) thread can come in, grab the mutex, and see a true value in `wakeUp` and exit without waiting. Another bug is that a thread which was waiting will wake up after `wakeUp` is reset and immediately resume waiting.

One way to resolve this is to use count - each thread that is waiting will increment the count, then the trigger will wait until that many threads have woken before resuming. You would then have to ensure that non-waiting threads are not allowed to start waiting until this had happened.

```
// wake up "waiters" count of waiting threads
void CEvent::trigger()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    // wakey wakey
    wakeUp = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&condition);

    // wait for them to awake
    while (waiters>0)
      pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &mutex);

    // stop waking threads up
    wakeUp = false;

    // let any "other" threads which were ready to start waiting, do so
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&condition);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

// wait for the condition to be notified for us
void CEvent::wait()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    // wait for us to be allowed to start waiting
    // we have to wait until any currrently being woken threads have gone
    while (wakeUp)
        pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &mutex);

    // our turn to start waiting
    waiters ++;

    // waiting
    while (!wakeUp)
        pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &mutex);

    // finished waiting, we were triggered
    waiters --;

    // let the trigger thread know we're done
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&condition);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```